# how to send message to Kafka cluster from outside of vpn

Tags: apache-kafka

we have 3 Kafka brokers in a cluster running in our private VPN. our client wants to send messages to our Kafka cluster. our admin has created public-IP for only one Kafka broker out of 3. client cluster is able to communicate with our VPN through this public-IP(checked using Wireshark), but we are not receiving any messages.

Whether we need to create public IPs for the remaining 2 Kafka brokers also?
Can anyone suggest what configs should we change in order to work?

Answer (score 0):

Clients are required to communicate directly with leader brokers of the partitions, so all brokers need to advertise some resolvable address for themselves through the VPN

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the VPN term wrong. You probably mean VPC or some kind of private network.

As mentioned by OneCricketeer you must assign public address to every broker. But also you must set `advertised.listeners` property or `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` to the public IP address or public DNS name pointing to that public address otherwise your client will not be able to connect.

More details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/